# Define a type which is a list of objects property values inside an array

Tags: typescript

I've an array of objects with a common property "name", like this one:

`const actionList = [{name: "a"}, {name: "b"}, {name: "c"}]`

I'm providing this array to an interface that should accept this array and another property that must allow one of the "name" values of the given array ( so only "a" | "b" | "c" ).

```
interface Action{
    name: string;
}

interface TestInterface<TActions extends Action[] = Action[]>{
    actions: TActions;
    actionName: TActions[number]["name"]
}
```

Using only `TActions[number]["name"]` I get a generic `string` type

```
const a1:TestInterface = { actions: actionList, actionName: "" } // Should only allow "a" | "b" | "c"
const a2:TestInterface = { actions: actionList, actionName: "a" } // Should be ok
const a3:TestInterface = { actions: actionList, actionName: "m" } // Should throw error
```

Is it possible?

[Here a link to a playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iA3gWAChkTkQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzAbiIF8iiEcHlEmHABlg-ALzIA2rnJVaAIjgKBdZLxAMOAGmSzKNZAoBGCnXrmGFCMwF1uhUJFiIUAFQgMAkuGjwkADxu6EKayBAAHpAgACZqIdggUrbIkgk4yQB8BMSkgol0tMEYBey5JPk4AHIGRemaUiAArhTG0LZSCpYK9oRchDx8YAIAjNQe3r4uSKl6AiV8tJUgogy6yzXyRiocyAD0e8gAygAWWE0ANjHIOBcAngIXF1gA7kbKyAA%20RqZfRjaDTTDOAAJnGnjAPmc-hQklw81ChQRiVWYHWCxAmysH12B2OZ0u1zaNwA1oD%20HAAMzgybQ1yzeHLJHLVHo0JYxQUHb7Q6nc5XZBgE5QV7hKAiqBAA)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible as long as you make your `actionList` immutable (e.g. by using a `const` assertion) and provide enough type information to the compiler:

```
interface Action{
    name: string;
}

const actionList = [{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }, { name: "c" }] as const;

interface TestInterface<TActions extends readonly Action[] = Action[]>{
    actions: TActions;
    actionName: TActions[number]["name"]
}

const a1: TestInterface<typeof actionList> = { actions: actionList, actionName: "" }; // Error
const a2: TestInterface<typeof actionList> = { actions: actionList, actionName: "a" }; // OK
const a3: TestInterface<typeof actionList> = { actions: actionList, actionName: "m" }; // Error
```